# Unable to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm currently causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that I can't seem to track down. I have a Spinner that is populated by a `String[]`. Depending on the manufacturer of the device, that `String[] (and hence Spinner object)` will have either 3 values or 1 value.

I store the saved Spinner selection as an `int` in the `SharedPreferences` and load it up upon the `Activity` creation.

In cases where the Spinner will only have 1 value, if it loads up the `SharedPreferences` and the saved value is `2`, I set that spinner to select item position 2, it will crash (obviously). I am trying to catch that exception so that I can then just set it to `0`, but I can't ever seem to catch that `Exception`.

The code structure is as so:

```
Populate Spinner according to something
Load up Saved Preferences
Check some value of saved preferences
try{
Set Spinner with that Preference
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Set Spinner with default value of 0
}
```

StackTrace:

`10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
10-18 12:49:32.885: E/AndroidRuntime(15327):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)`

Comment: Is it possible the exception was thrown outside the try block? Can't tell if that's case from what you have posted here.

Comment: It is certain that the error is caused by setting the spinner with an index that is outside of it's available choices, as when I remove it, it's all fine. I even wrapped the entire onCreate() (from which this section of code is invoked from) to catch the exception, but it still does not catch it.

Comment: Interesting. One level up Exception is the Java Throwable. Wonder if that allows you to catch it.

Comment: Try to debug ... you should be able to find the point that fire the error and, in case, manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Or even better: If you know exactly what exception is potentially being thrown, just catch that rather then a generic RunTimeException.

```
try{
    Set Spinner with that Preference 
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    Set Spinner with default value of 0
}
```

This makes it very clear to anyone reading your code what is happening.

Also, it's not great style to use try/catch to handle run time exceptions. It would be must better style to check the array length before attempting to use the array. If the length is too short, you can drop into an else loop or something and set the Spinner with default value of 0 with the exception never being thrown. This makes your code a lot easier to read, and creates a lot lower chance of another developer coming along and not understanding exactly what your try/catch block is doing and breaking your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that your proposed solution is much better - and I am likely to change to that. But from a purely educational standpoint, I'm unsure of why it's happening. I actually had your solution (catching the exact error) but it still does not catch it. I've even attempted to wrap the entire onCreate() in the try to test what's going on, and even then it doesn't catch it. Any ideas?